# Javascript form validation doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I have an input box. Upon submit, I have a PHP script which checks to see if the input box is empty. If it is, it displays an error message and runs a Javascript function.

My problem is that the error message appears, but the Javascript function doesn't execute.

Here's my script:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if(empty($username)) {
        echo 'Please enter a username';

        echo"
            <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                function validate(e) {
                    var username = document.getElementById('username');
                    if (username.value.trim() == '') {
                        username.classList.add('error');

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            username.classList.remove('error');
                        }, 300);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
            ";

    }else{
        // something here
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" id="login">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're just echoing out your JS, not executing it. You really would benefit from [using AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) to do this. Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: The browser console doesn't appear do be displaying any errors

Comment: You are attempting to process JavaScript at the server (in PHP)... this won't work.  You need to add the JavaScript to the output page in order for it to run in the browser.

Comment: @scunliffe: The code *is* outputting the JavaScript to the page.  Note the use of `echo` and the fact that it's wrapped in a string literal.

Comment: @scunliffe I had previously tried that, but the Javascript wouldn't execute as the form kept refreshing on submit.

Comment: @David yes, but it is only output to the HTML stream **AFTER** he has posted the form back to the server. (cart before the horse issue)

Comment: @scunliffe: It's backwards, I'll grant you that.  But it's not trying to process the JavaScript on the server.

Comment: @David true... it isn't really trying to process on the server, but the logic is flawed in terms of where and when it renders.  The javascript needs to be **Outside** of the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` block of code, otherwise this will never work.

Comment: @scunliffe: It will "work" depending on the definition of "work".  The client-side validation being performed may be *moot* in this case because server-side validation has *already* been performed, but the validation can still successfully execute nonetheless.  It's pointless, but it can logically do what it's designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Where does your JavaScript function actually get *executed*?  Removing the logic, the *structure* of what you have is:

```
window.onload = function () {
  function validate(e) {
    //...
  }
}
```

So when the window loads, you execute a function.  That function does nothing more than define another function.  Nothing ever *executes* that other function.

If you want to execute that code when the window loads, don't wrap it in a function.  Just execute it:

```
window.onload = function () {
  // validation logic here
}
```

Comment: My objective is to run the script if the input box is empty - that's why it's inside `if(empty($loginusername))`

Comment: @questershelp: Ok.  What does that change?  The ordering of the logic is a little unusual, though.  Normally client-side validation is performed *before* server-side validation.  And when outputting an invalid form, you don't really *need* to perform client-side validation because you already *know* that it isn't valid.

Comment: I had put the Javascript separate, but it wouldn't execute as the form kept refreshing on submit.

Comment: @questershelp: Sounds like there was an error with the logic in that case.  Correcting that error would likely be more useful in the long run than reversing the logic.  In this design, the entire JavaScript component is basically moot.

Comment: Do you suggest I move the Javascript back out of the PHP script?

Comment: @questershelp: Well, I suggest that you perform client-side validation *before* posting to the server. How you organize that code isn't really the point. You can keep the JavaScript on the same page, move it to a separate `.js` file, etc. But the JavaScript should be emitted to the page when it *first* loads, and should be bound to the form's submit event. When that event fires, if the validation fails then the event should be interrupted. If it passes, the event can continue and the form can be posted. (Which should, of course, re-validate since user input should never be implicitly trusted.)